# SQL Server append XML child nodes to parent node

Tags: sql-server, xml, append, xmlnode, xml.modify

I need to have a script which can insert / append new xml child nodes to a pre-existing xml parent node.

```
--New child nodes
DECLARE @XMLChildData XML
SET @XMLChildData = '
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Gary</Firstname>
        <Surname>Smith</Surname>
        <Telephone>0115547899</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>1 Church Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rosebank</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Houghton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Wayne</Firstname>
        <Surname>Farmey</Surname>
        <Telephone>0117453269</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>51 Oak Street</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rivionia</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Sandton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Mark</Firstname>
        <Surname>Jones</Surname>
        <Telephone>0119854741</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>4 Arum Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Glen Hazel</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Johannesburg</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
</Persons>'

--Existing parent node
DECLARE @XMLParentData XML
SET @XMLParentData = '
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Sarah</Firstname>
        <Surname>Gray</Surname>
        <Telephone>0113265874</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>78 Emerl Aveune</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Fourways</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Sandton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Jenna</Firstname>
        <Surname>Reed</Surname>
        <Telephone>0114781102</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>6 Park Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Parkhurst</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rosebank</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Mike</Firstname>
        <Surname>Wilke</Surname>
        <Telephone>0116532003</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>22 High Road</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Modderfontein</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Edenvale</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
</Persons>'
```

I want the end result to be:

```
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Sarah</Firstname>
        <Surname>Gray</Surname>
        <Telephone>0113265874</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>78 Emerl Aveune</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Fourways</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Sandton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Jenna</Firstname>
        <Surname>Reed</Surname>
        <Telephone>0114781102</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>6 Park Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Parkhurst</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rosebank</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Mike</Firstname>
        <Surname>Wilke</Surname>
        <Telephone>0116532003</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>22 High Road</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Modderfontein</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Edenvale</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Gary</Firstname>
        <Surname>Smith</Surname>
        <Telephone>0115547899</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>1 Church Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rosebank</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Houghton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Wayne</Firstname>
        <Surname>Farmey</Surname>
        <Telephone>0117453269</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>51 Oak Street</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Rivionia</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Sandton</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Firstname>Mark</Firstname>
        <Surname>Jones</Surname>
        <Telephone>0119854741</Telephone>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>4 Arum Lane</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Glen Hazel</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>Johannesburg</AddressLine>
            <AddressLine>South Africa</AddressLine>
        </Address>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

I know i need to use the .modify(), however i am not sure how to iterate through the child nodes and insert / append each child `"<person>"` node into the parent `"<persons>"` node.

I would think it would need to be something similiar as below

```
SET @XMLParentData.modify('
    insert     
        (
            sql:variable("@XMLChildData")
        )
    after
        (/Person[1]/Person[1])
')

SELECT @XMLData
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the `Person` nodes from @XMLChildData to a separate variable and add that to the `Persons` node of `@XMLParentData`.

```sql
DECLARE @PersonList XML

SET @PersonList = @XMLChildData.query('Persons/*')

SET @XMLParentData.modify('insert sql:variable("@PersonList") as last into /Persons[1]')

SELECT @XMLParentData
```

Another way is to extract the `Person` nodes from both variables and rebuild the `Persons` node using `FOR XML PATH`.

```sql
SET @XMLParentData = (
                     SELECT @XMLParentData.query('/Persons/Person'),
                            @XMLChildData.query('/Persons/Person')
                     FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Persons'), TYPE
                     )
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, if I take your first code snippet I have the same problem as with Bummi suggestion, were I seem to be appending the <persons> list from the child node into the parent <persons> list. I wish to have only the parent xml with a root node of <persons> and append only the <person> nodes from the child xml into the parent xml. If I take your second code snippet it works as expected. How could I achieve the required result with your first code snippet. I wish to understand what I did wrong so I may better myself.

Comment: @user3917837 The first works as expected. You probably just forgot to change what variable you use in `sql:variable`. Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40302).